# making a 3 cube spin with reactJs but getting an error message thrown. Is this the right approach?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I hope I can explain myself well...
I have a 3D cube that I'd like to spin while a button is hovered.
So,

1. I made two states. 'mouseover' set to false, 'deg' set to 0.
2. When the event 'onMouseEnter' is triggered on a button, I set 'mouseover' to true. 'onMouseLeave', to false.
3. When 'mouseover' is true, I want to increase the 'y' axis of the cube by 1 continously.
4. So I set both 'deg' and 'mouseover' as a dependency in useEffect.

Result is, the cube spins everytime I hover the button.. seems like it's working
but in the console I get this message thrown.

```
react-dom.development.js:86 Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen 
when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a 
dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render
```

Seems like I'm missing something. What it would be?

here is my codes.

```
function Nav() {
    const [deg, setDeg] = useState(0);
    const [mouseover, setMouseOver] = useState(false);

    useEffect(()=>{
        if (mouseover === true) {
            setDeg(deg+1);
        }
        else {
            setDeg(deg);
        }
    }, [mouseover, deg])

    function entered(e) {
        setMouseOver(true);
    }

    function out(e) {
        setMouseOver(false);
}

    return (
        <div className='container'>
            <button className='btn btn1' onMouseEnter={entered} onMouseLeave={out}> button </button>
            {/* transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 0deg); */}

            <div className="cube" style={{transform: `rotate3d(0, 1, 0, ${deg}deg)`}}>
                <div className="side front">HIHI</div>
                <div className="side left">sadfasfasdf</div>
                <div className="side right">fffffffffffffffff</div>
                <div className="side back"> sadfjadois fjaisdof</div>
                <div className="side top"> asdfj siodajf iaosd</div>
                <div className="side bottom"> asdfadsi jaosdij f</div>
            </div>
            <button className='btn btn1' onMouseEnter={entered} onMouseLeave={out}> button </button>
    </div>
)
```

}

Enlighten me please and also, is there any better approach to make this cube spin? thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get the error is that you have no timeouts between updates.

You can do it in pure CSS

```css
.rotate-me {
  background: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.rotate-me:hover {
    animation: rotation 2s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes rotation {
    from {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        transform: rotate(359deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="rotate-me">hover me</div>
```

This is a simple example, you can toggle a specific class name on hover, use scss (for nesting of selectors) or use your favorite styling framework

Comment: Hi, can you give me an example of how to set a time out?

Comment: useEffect(
  setTimeout(setDeg, 500, deg + 1);
}, [deg]);